# can't connect to PostgreSQL in Docker from IntelliJ Idea

Tags: postgresql, docker, intellij-idea

I have Docker on Windows 11, I have pulled the latest "postgres" image using the Docker UI.

I run the container using this command:

`docker run --name localpostgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pg12345 -p 5432:5432 -d postgres`

I connect successfully to the database in the container:

`docker exec -it localpostgres /bin/bash`

`psql -d postgres -U postgres`

(it doesn't ask for the password which is strange, it just lets me in)

Now I'm trying to set up a connection from IntelliJ Idea and it's failing when I click "Test connection" (see the picture). The result is the same when I use either "pg12345" or an empty password.

[image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong? What is missing here?

**Update:**
Screenshots with the error.
[image]
[image]

**Update 2:**
Accidentally found out that the actual password was "postgres", so this command did not set the password to my custom value:
`docker run --name localpostgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pg12345 -p 5432:5432 -d postgres`

Comment: "doesn't ask for the password which is strange" That's not strange; that's how it's configured; see `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf`. Local connections (connections originating from inside the container) are trusted.

Comment: Do you see an entry in the container log (`docker logs localpostgres`) in response to the failed connection?

Comment: The picture doesn't show any error message.

Comment: I've updated my post, added a couple of screenshots. Unfortunately, they are unreadable, despite the fact that I've switched my OS interface language to English (it was using cyrillic characters).

Comment: I've found the cause of the error accidentally. See the "Update 2" (wrong password).

Comment: I've checked the logs, there was no error message. Just one strange thing: it has the message "starting PostgreSQL 15.3" in the logs but the IDE says it has successfully connected to PostgreSQL 14.1. It's not a different instance, this container in the only one PostgreSQL, and I have no local installation. Anyway, it's connected now.